# Creating png file on dropbox for shiny app

Tags: r, dropbox, shiny

I'm actually creating a shiny app that is hosted on `shinyapps.io`. 
To read and use my data I communicate with a dropbox account with `rdrop2` package. 
I'd like to create a png file according to the user's input on my dropbox. 
Usually, I create png file on my working directory like that :

```
png("test.png") 
plot(...) 
dev.off()
```

I don't save just plots as PNG but also grid.tables.

I can get a file from my dropbox with 'drop_get' function.

My only problem is that I don't know how to save my instantly created png directly on my dropbox. I tried to save my PNG file in a variable like `varPNG<-png('test.png')`... and saved it with 'drop_upload' function but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Shouldn't drop_upload just take the filename? (And not the variable). As in drop_upload("test.png")?

Comment: Absolutely, this is why it doesn't work at all. But when I use png("test.png")...dev.off(), I think (not sure) that the png can't be save on my computer (server) (especially when I try the application with another computer) so I can't use drop_upload("test.png") because png() will not save the image directly on my dropbox. My app works well on local but online a message says "Disconnected from the server" and reload the app when I'm rendering the images.

Comment: What do you mean by "server"?
png() won't directly upload to dropbox no. It saves on the same directory as your app. That's why you use rdrop2 to take the file and put it on your dropbox.
I'm guessing you have some kind of authorisation issue with your app when used online.

Comment: I thought that but when I don't see the png files on my app directory. Maybe that I do another  mistake but my code works and save png files on my working directory when I locally test my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
I'm not familiar enough with shiny app to help, sorry.
Though I did find this thing: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/image-output.html which might help you out.

Basically it seems shiny has a `renderImage` function to manage the creation of images. Hope this helps.

OLD ANSWER:

The documentation for the package is [here](https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2) for reference.

Make sure you have allowed rdrop2 to access your dropbox (see link)!

From the link:

```
write.csv(mtcars, 'mtcars.csv')
drop_upload('mtcars.csv')
# or upload to a specific folder
drop_upload('mtcars.csv', dest = "drop_test")

You can also do this for any other file type and large files are supported regardless of your memory.
```

So you shouldn't store your image in a variable and try and upload that.
Instead save your file as you would do as usual and then do:

```
drop_upload("filename.png")
```

Comment: Thx but when I use drop_upload("filename.png") I think that my app doesn't find the file that I created. In my loop i do: 
png(paste("test",les_nb[i],".png)",sep=""),width=350,height=145)
...
dev.off()
...
drop_upload(file=paste("test",les_nb[i],".png",sep=""),dest='optimaentendre/Images')
...
eval(parse(text=paste("output$table",les_nb[i]," <- renderImage({return(list(src=drop_get('optimaentendre/Images/test",les_nb[i],".png'),width=ifelse(donneCateg(i+1)==12,300,250), height=ifelse(donneCateg(i+1)==12,150,350)))},deleteFile=F)",sep="")))

So I think that I do what you propose

Comment: You said it worked locally. Do you see the files online? Not in dropbox, but on the server.

Comment: Also does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177033/shinyapp-dropbox-authentication-with-rdrop2

Comment: Where can I see the "files online" ? For the link that you gave I used it yesterday to connect my app with my dropbox account. I already can read files (csv) with drop_read_csv on my dropbox account when my app is online. When my app is online, my getwd() gives "/srv/connect/apps/myApp" so I tried png("/srv/connect/apps/myApp/test.png")....renderImage("/srv/connect/apps/myApp/test.png") but the app still says "Disconnected from the server" at the moment where the app has to create and render the images.